# My supervisors and the VP meet me in private to tell me to lower the quality of my work, any advice?

Tags: work-environment

I am engineer and in my spare time I pursue a PhD. I developed as a consultant and recently I decided to become a quantitative analyst at an energy trading company.

When I was recruited for this new position I was told that they were expecting nothing but the best, so I felt that I could really develop there.

After getting some assignments and fulfilling those with state of the art tools and methods, **I was called over by my manager and another mid range manager to tell me that I should lower the quality** (A.K.A use simpler methods. I.e. linear two-variable regression instead of multidimensional deep learning) because "others" might feel threatened by the new developments. They also told me the they still were expecting to be mesmerized by my work.

I did talk to my peers to get a feeling of how was I being perceived by doing this kind of work, and they were alright with it, actually some wanted to learn and others already at my same or higher level. I want to stress that I am no math wizard, just a guy that does a state of the art review before proceeding with an assignment.

After this puzzling episode, I got a quite hard assignment. I did a bit of bibliography research and I found a paper describing the problem and proposing a solution. This solution involved some probabilistic math that I acknowledge that is not straight forward, but it got the job done.

After this I got called apart, this time by the company vice president. Same message; "Be average and lower the quality, you'll be happier, but we still expect great things of you"

I told the managers that it was very hard for me to do something "average" when I know the best. This is specially relevant because a part of my salary will come based on the financial performance of the tools I develop.

I also feel that if I deliver bad quality, I am not being honest with my self.

**Any advice?**

PS: I believe that all this comes because new methods represent more work for the company managers since they would have to catch up with them.

Comment: How much time are you spending on your "high quality" solution? It could be that they would rather have you use simpler, good-enough methods that take up less of your time.

Comment: I take almost the same time since I use off-the-shelf libraries. I do all the work in python which is highly productive for data analysis. In fact I am idle   some days while I get feedback.

Comment: Their idea of "quality" and your idea of "quality" aren't the same.

Comment: It's a bit unclear if they are communicating poorly or you are confused by what they are saying. Perhaps you should ask them if the team is coming to them and complaining about the complexity of your work or if they feel that while your solutions are great they feel that you're spending 50% extra time to make the solution 10% better. Hopefully you get can get them to give you a straight answer and not "beat around the bush". I'm guessing that they want you to provide a solution that is just good enough to get the job done and move on to the next project.

Comment: Sounds like it's your supervisor and VP that are threatened by your work...

Comment: "*Any advice*" About? What is you **goal** here? Argue that you should be allowed to keep coding as you are? Finding a compromise? Teaching your colleagues about the stuff you use? I ask because a generic "What would you do?" is not a suitable question here because we quite simply can't decide how you should feel about something or how you should react to it.

Comment: And since this seems to be a translation, are you sure that they had a problem with the **quality** of your code rather than the **complexity**? There's a difference between "*You're doing so well you're making us all look bad.*" and "*The stuff you write is so 'elegant' that no one can make sense of it.*". The latter isn't a compliment.

Comment: If you really had a problem that could be solved with linear regression and you used multidimensional deep learning instead, the problem isn't quality.

Comment: Did they actually ask you to _lower the quality of your work_? Or did they ask you to change your work in a way that you perceive as _lowering the quality_?

Comment: They actually fired me.

Comment: So I guess the lesson here is: When you get the "lower your quality call" start looking somewhere else.

Comment: I would look for a new job. Quality and perfection are apart of what drives you and where you get your reward and enjoyment from work, I would not commit to that compromise.

Comment: @Peter if it produces a better fit and increased $ for the company it is

Comment: Another possibility:  They don't want a bus factor of 1.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel in that case they should not advertise the position as looking for the very best, as OP mentioned. It is completely fine to use more simple solutions, but then you should not use superlatives in the job description. It would be false advertisement and leads exactly to what happened to OP.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen I guess it recruits people who think they are the very best, but in reality don't know how to work as part of a team or are missing other fundamental skills for success.

Answer (score 14):

Some of the more theoretical advantages of simpler methods:

- They are more often transparent (c.f. a neural net). It is possible to explain to a client why a decision was made for instance, or possible to reproduce the works yourself.
- They are faster to train or run.
- They are easier to verify.
- They are more robust under slight changes in training data.

Some of the more practical advantages of simpler methods:

- They take much less time to develop.
- They are easier to review.
- They are easier to debug.
- They are easier to explain.
- They work just as well most of the time.

If you don't understand all of these considerations *in addition to* whatever is state of the art in the field, then **please, do not work for me or with me.** To be honest I'm pretty sure something is missing from your story. There is clearly a way your work is not as high quality as you think and the answer is not "it's too brilliant." Shame on your management for not properly articulating this to you, but, kudos to you for posting here to try to find out what it is.

That being said, I do want to hire someone who:

- has the knowledge to move our way of doing things forward
- can teach hard things to coworkers
- is jovial and fun to work with even when the work is hard
- can balance many dimensions of concerns (i.e. the above list)

It sounds like you are adding this sort of value. But you are doing something wrong and you don't know what yet. Keep looking for it.

Comment: You may want to add a reference to [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) to this answer. (The professor in my first Machine Learning class referred to it as a guideline for model/method selection and I found that to be the most important take away message from that course. It's so easy to overfit on training data...)

Comment: Fully agree, that simpler methods work better some times. In fact I have applied linear regressions for other problems. But the issue here is how to deal with bosses that feel intimidated by you.

Comment: @user721807 I don't think they are, I think they're just annoyed the team has to maintain unnecessarily complicated solutions.

Comment: I guess then excel with VBA's is easier than 10 lines of python

Comment: @user721807 I'm just saying that for quite many involved questions like this it's best to be skeptical of the OP's narrative.

Answer (score 2):

#### Raise the quality of the team

Rather than lower your quality, raise your fellow peers' quality.  Normally I would not suggest something like this, but you stated:

> actually some wanted to learn

and

> In fact I am idle some days while I get feedback

Having coworkers that are open and willing to learn from fellow coworkers is something to treasure.  So for your peers that have indicated they would like to learn take that idle time you have and use it to teach/help/show them your tricks and techniques.

There is a second reason for this strategy.  It is possible that your coworkers are trying to be diplomatic/polite with you more than being honest.  Your peers may have said something to management or the VPs in casual or formal conversation about feeling intimidated by you, which is something they would never say to you.  By trying to teach them it can help alleviate this or draw it to the surface that way you would be aware of it.

Third, if management continues to be annoyed with your higher quality, firing you would not solve the problem.  After all you have taught many more people on the team to be just as much of a problem *cough...* I mean awesome.

#### Take note of other peers accomplishments

> and others already at my same or higher level

If you have peers doing similar or better accomplishments with what they are working on take note of it.  That way if someone pulls you aside again, you can cite other people's accomplishments as a defense to your own work. Saying something like:

> I can see how me applying [Random important person's] algorithm to the data problem may seem impressive, but Bob just last week applied [Someone totally different's] algorithm to that other problem which from my technical perspective was far more challenging.  In comparison what I did was rather average.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a key line:

> PS: I believe that all this comes because new methods represent more work for the company managers since they would have to catch up with them.

I imagine that the managers want you to develop methods which make *less* work for them.  There is an ROI on their and your colleagues' coming up to speed on new methodologies.

Consider the benefits of your method ... does it benefit the company to use it?  Are your more accurate results creating a better/safer/sexier/cheaper product, or just adding significant digits which can be ignored?  Not being snarky here, it's an honest question which you should be asking.

So, let's say your method is better, saves the company money.  How much money (time is money, yo) does it cost to train everyone and change processes?  This is a comparison you should make.

Okay, you've done these calculations.  Let's say that your way is better, saves money, isn't too expensive to implement.  *Now* go and talk to manager types about it, **armed with your analysis of the benefits**.

I bet you'll have a lot more success pitching your idea if you can tie it to quantifiable company benefit rather than to your sense of professional pride.  Seriously, why would they want to leave money on the table?  Your job is to show them it's there.